# Need a component to connect a 9v water pump

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

I have a 9v water pump that i want to turn on\off from the arduino,
What module should i use to turn it on and off?

I am using now a mosfet for my 5v pump, can a mosfet be used for 9v as well? Or is there some better solution?

Comment: Yes, a MOSFET, that can be used with 9V (as most of them do). Refer to the datasheet of your MOSFET

Comment: Is there any suggestion?

Comment: There are many possible MOSFETs that you can use. Look at the maximum values for the drain-source-voltage and check, that the threshold voltage lies around 2.5V or lower, so that the MOSFET is fully conductive, when you turn the Arduinos output on. Also look, if the maximum current lies over the current, that your pump needs. You can provide a link or at least a part number to your MOSFET in your question. Then we could say, if you can use it for the 9V pump. (You also need to provide the needed current value).

Comment: More useful information about MOSFETs can be found here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29065/how-to-control-a-12v-solenoid-valve-with-a-mosfet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a MOSFET should work just fine. As others have said in the comments, you just need to make sure that it's rated for your desired voltage and current, and that it's threshold voltage is low enough (around 2.5V) that the Arduino is able to drive it to saturation with a logic level 1 (5V).

I've used this one (rated at 60V and 30A) in various projects:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10213